# Unable to run meteor app locally windows 7

Tags: meteor

I'm having trouble running my app from the command prompt line. I'm not used to running apps, etc. from the terminal. I'll show you what I get below.

```
    C:\Windows\system32>meteor create newapp
newapp: created.

To run your new app:
  cd newapp
  meteor

C:\Windows\system32>cd newapp/meteor
The system cannot find the path specified.

C:\Windows\system32>cd newapp

C:\Windows\system32>meteor
run: You're not in a Meteor project directory.
```

Am I typing it in wrong? What am I doing wrong. I followed the tutorial on their website and still unable to run it. Also, the app isn't even being created, I can't find it on my system?

---

Now when I try to run it, I'm getting this error
**Tasklist error**

```
  => Started proxy.

C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.1.3\mt-os.windows.x86
_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\fibers\future.js:278
                                                throw(ex);
                                                      ^
Error: Couldn't run tasklist.exe: tasklist wasn't found on your system, it usual
ly can be found at C:\Windows\System32\.
    at Object.Future.wait (C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-t
ool\1.1.3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\fibers\future.js:398:
15)
    at findMongoPids (C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1
.1.3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\tools\run-mongo.js:120:16)
    at findMongoAndKillItDead (C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\mete
or-tool\1.1.3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\tools\run-mongo.js:236:14)
    at launchOneMongoAndWaitForReadyForInitiate (C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\.me
teor\packages\meteor-tool\1.1.3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\tools\run-mongo.js:360:7)
    at launchMongo (C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.1
.3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\tools\run-mongo.js:612:7)
    at [object Object]._.extend._startOrRestart (C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\.me
teor\packages\meteor-tool\1.1.3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\tools\run-mongo.js:712:19)
    at [object Object]._.extend.start (C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\.meteor\packa
ges\meteor-tool\1.1.3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\tools\run-mongo.js:670:10)
    at C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.1.3\mt-os.wind
ows.x86_32\tools\run-all.js:199:26
    - - - - -
    at C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.1.3\mt-os.wind
ows.x86_32\tools\run-mongo.js:73:24
    at exithandler (child_process.js:654:7)
    at ChildProcess.errorhandler (child_process.js:670:5)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:818:12)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want to create anything in the C:\Windows\system32 folder.
This is probably the reason why your application is not created.

Create a directory somewhere else, dedicated to your developments.
C:\Dev, C:\Projects for exemple.

Then, go to your directory, hold down the Shift key and right-click, the context menu should contain "Open command window here".

Then, you can run your meteor commands.

Comment: When I run it and visit `http://localhost:3000/` I'm getting this webpage is not available. ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED I'm using WAMP

Comment: You don't need wamp to run your meteor application. But I don't think this is what causing the error. Do you have any errors in the command window? (When you run meteor)

Comment: Yes, I will post them to my question now, 1 minute.

Comment: There is a similar issue: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/4128 Make sur C:\Windows\System32 is in your system path.

Comment: Thanks, how do I add the path C:\Windows\System32 to my original path? How do I add the path to the tasklist?

Comment: In the command window: setx path "%path%;C:\Windows\system32"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75723/discussion-between-crsmc-and-mrshibby).

Comment: @MrShibby : hold down the Shift key and right-click, the context menu should contain "Open command window here". not working for me. got same error . please help me :(

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75723/discussion-between-crsmc-and-mrshibby Maybe you'll find an anwser here.