# Meteor on Windows 7: meteor command outputs error

Tags: windows, meteor

Recently I installed meteor version 1.1.0.2 on my windows 7 (32bit) pc. When I create a project by `meteor create myapp` it creates a project for me. But after `cd myapp` when i press `meteor` command it shows an error.
Here is the error message in my cmd prompt:

```
C:\Users\imran\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.1.3\mt-os.windows.x8
6_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\fibers\future.js:278
                                                throw(ex);
                                                      ^
Error: Couldn't run tasklist.exe: tasklist wasn't found on your system, it usual
ly can be found at C:\Windows\System32\.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29748366/unable-to-run-meteor-app-locally-windows-7

Comment: not getting any proper solution :(

Answer (score 0):

If you can find **tasklist.exe** under **C:\Windows\System32** then you probably don't have C:\Windows\System32 added to your PATH.

Adding C:\Windows\System32 to my PATH (environment variable) worked for me :)

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem 
so i went into my Environment Variables
under system variables added new PATH (in caps)
then directed it to C:\Windows\System32

though there was a path there initially (with a whole bunch of other things pointing to different places) adding C:\Windows\System32  to this didn't seem to work for me. so i created a new one

then i ran a new cmd session as administrator.
works fine now