# Unable to Run Meteor 1.1.0.3 Application Locally Windows 10 (Tasklist.exe)

Tags: windows, powershell, meteor

I need some help please.

I just did a fresh install of Meteor 1.1.0.3 from the website using the windows installer. That worked just fine.

I then created one of the sample applications. That worked just fine.

The problem is when I try to run the app and the first package starts to download, I get an exception error. I have Googled this issue for a couple hours now and cannot find a solution.

**Here is the CMD output Error:**

---

```html
C:\Users\jwuli\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.1.4\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\fibers\
future.js:278
                                                throw(ex);
                                                      ^
Error: Couldn't run tasklist.exe: tasklist wasn't found on your system, it usually can be found at C:\Windows\System32\.

    at Object.Future.wait (C:\Users\jwuli\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.1.4\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bund
le\lib\node_modules\fibers\future.js:398:15)
    at findMongoPids (C:\Users\jwuli\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.1.4\mt-os.windows.x86_32\tools\run-mon
go.js:120:16)
    at findMongoAndKillItDead (C:\Users\jwuli\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.1.4\mt-os.windows.x86_32\tool
s\run-mongo.js:236:14)
    at launchOneMongoAndWaitForReadyForInitiate (C:\Users\jwuli\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.1.4\mt-os.w
indows.x86_32\tools\run-mongo.js:360:7)
    at launchMongo (C:\Users\jwuli\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.1.4\mt-os.windows.x86_32\tools\run-mongo
.js:612:7)
    at [object Object]._.extend._startOrRestart (C:\Users\jwuli\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.1.4\mt-os.w
indows.x86_32\tools\run-mongo.js:712:19)
    at [object Object]._.extend.start (C:\Users\jwuli\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.1.4\mt-os.windows.x86
_32\tools\run-mongo.js:670:10)
    at C:\Users\jwuli\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.1.4\mt-os.windows.x86_32\tools\run-all.js:199:26
    - - - - -
    at C:\Users\jwuli\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.1.4\mt-os.windows.x86_32\tools\run-mongo.js:73:24
    at exithandler (child_process.js:654:7)
    at ChildProcess.errorhandler (child_process.js:670:5)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:818:12)
```

I am able to run tasklist.exe in any command window and see all my running process.

There is another user here that had the EXACT same issue but on Windows 7. What worked for him was opening the command prompt directly from the root directory of the project. This solution did not work for me.

That post is here: [Other Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29748366/unable-to-run-meteor-app-locally-windows-7)

I have also tried Powershell along with CMD both running as the Administrator.

Does anyone have any insight?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So after allot of research, and working with other similar platforms/frameworks. I found out that there are many dependencies that you need to install that are not listed in the normal documentation. Examples being, Python, Ruby for the Saas Gem. A ton of old windows C++ Distributabls.

As a Full Stack .NET developer all these concepts were new to me! Everything is working just fine now.